# How do I use HTML text area input as a string for a perl script?

Tags: html, perl, textarea, global-variables

As of now I have two separate scripts: one that just prints the html to generate a text box and submit button which opens a link to /~gen13/wordrate.cgi. That directory (on our class server) contains the second script which, in theory, should take the text the user entered and return some values.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to access the input to the first file's text box with the second file. I have read into open and use commands, but I do not know how I would refer to the input or if an accessible input is being created at all (I'm worried I just have a text box that won't lead anywhere...).

The HTML script is here, it currently creates the box with a functional submit button that properly calls the second script, but the second script lacks an actual calling of the input:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use vars qw($
print header;

###Form Create###
        &create_form;

sub create_form {
print ("<html><head><title>Wordy: Your One
Stop Verbosity Shop</title></head>\n<body>\n");
print ("WELCOME TO WORDY: YOUR ONE STOP VERBOSITY SHOP $vote<p>\n");

print <<endHTML;
<form action="/~gen13/wordrate.cgi" method="POST" target="_blank">
<textarea name="text" cols=120 rows=12>
Please enter your text...
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="WORDIFY">
</form>
</body>
        </html>
endHTML
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

A hidden field could be used to xfer the info. This passes the first script's `foo` parameter to the second script as its `bar` parameter.

```
print '<input type="hidden" name="bar" value="'.escapeHTML(param('foo')).'">';
```

If they're on the same domain, cookies could also be used to share either the value itself, or a session id that would help locate the data stored on the server by the first script.

Comment: sorry, im not too familiar with html or how to implement session id's or cookies

how exactly would I go about integrating that into the second script? as of now the it just describes a few subroutines and refers to a variable (called $text in the code, but not referring to anything)

Comment: To create a session to store information locally and give the browser some kind of token it will provide back to the server in future requests. Cookies are usually used since they are perfect for this.